# Stealth keylogger for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keylogger

I would like to test detection of a stealth keylogger for Windows (preferably one that works well on Windows 10).

Where can I find either a closed or open source keylogger that does not appear in the Task Manager?

Comment: Not appear in Task Manager's "applications" or "processes" tab?

Comment: I don't want to accuse you of anything bad – but this has a bad touch/connotation, as if you want to test detection on computers other than yours. Afraid that will keep many from even attempting to answer.

Comment: I'm with @Izzy here.  If it wasn't for the "stealth" part, I'd be ok with an answer, but wanting it to not be detectable, that's a little, suspicious to say the least.  Not sure that's something this community should be helping with.

Comment: lol - Why not?  I've got my own virtual machine I'm testing with and I'm interested in the technology and in writing custom code that can detect them.  I recommend everyone "man up".  Geeze .. @Thomas, yes that's correct

Comment: [Ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/asking-questions-about-potentially-bad-software)

Comment: If someone can find it, it does not match the "stealth" requirement any more :-)

Comment: You could try looking for viruses classified as Trojan-Spy.Win32.KeyLogger

Comment: Also on [meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/why-was-this-answer-deleted), related to why you don't get answers. Maybe you want to enhance the question.

Comment: Thanks for idea @Thomas, was hoping there would either be open source or installable software vs something as seemingly dangerous as a virus, but that might be a place to start.  On enhancement - Any suggestions on how to enhance?  I initially figured that people might be aware of some in existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to test ...

Being a Test Manager I'd say you don't need a single product but many products in order to test whether your anti-keylogger works well with any of them and not only with a single one. Other than that, it seems there's no need to find out the most suitable one, since they are only used for the purpose of being detected. Any other features or usability are not important.

I'd like to add one more requirement for this scenario, which is the availability of a trial version, since you potentially don't want to buy all of them, because you don't want to use them actually. All of the following have a trial version available.

The [list on keyloggers.com](http://www.keyloggers.com/) was helpful to find these programs which match your requirements:

> works well on Windows 10

The website has tested on Windows 8, so I looked up all of them to see if they are advertised for Windows 10.

> a stealth keylogger ... not appear in the Task Manager

This is already a criterion on the website itself, so I analyzed only those which were listed as "Hidden in Task Manager".

Here's the remaining list of products that match your expectation. I am listing the direct links to the vendors, not the highly advertised ones on keyloggers.com:

- [Spytech SpyAgent Standard Edition](http://www.spytech-web.com/download.shtml#spyagent), ~70 USD
- [Relytec All In One Keylogger](http://www.relytec.com/), ~60 USD
- [REFOG Personal Monitor](http://www.refog.com/parental-monitoring-software.html), ~70 USD
- [SoftActivity Keylogger](http://www.softactivity.com/softactivity-keylogger/), ~50 USD
- [Elite Keylogger](https://www.elitekeyloggers.com/), ~80 USD

Comment: Good point on multiple installs to test - Thanks for resource, didn't know that existed .. Unfortunate they're all / mostly paid versions but I'll still purchase more than one to get a more reliable result.  Thanks again!

Comment: Google search got me something called Ardamax. Is that any good, or it is just a fraud. To me it seemed like malicious itself.